# Copy files from hard drive when booting from pen drive

Tags: usb, permissions, usb-drive

My Ubuntu system (16.04) has crashed.
before I re-install it, I need to copy some files in the home folder on the hard drive to the pen drive.
But since I am booting from the pen drive, I don't have reading rights for the files, so I cannot copy them.
How can I get around this?
Thanks

Comment: Use `sudo cp /... /....`

Comment: @Orm you want to copy files from home folder to the same pen-drive you have booted? or other pen-drive?

Comment: You need to have built your "pen drive" with "persistent storage". If you have an "Encrypted HOME directory", search on AskUbuntu, and be sure to backup `/home/.ecryptfs` as well as `/home/$USER`.

Comment: For copying home directory you want to use rsync, (or grsyc for gui). not cp. If you have a /home partition you can clone it using gparted copy/paste.

Comment: You may need to copy individual files as root, for 16.04, download gksu and run gksu nautilus. you should then be able to copy and paste the files.